# What is the most convinient and simple formula to calculate rating from views and favorites count?

Tags: web, rating

I have some content on my site with two parameters: 
- the number of views
- the number of people who added the item to theis favorites.

I want to propose some formula to combine those two parameter in some one parameter, i.e. "rating of the item".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a really good formula to calculate position in ranking, when you've got users *voting* for particular items.

```
rating = (g / (g+m)) * s + (m / (g+m)) * S
```

- `s` is average rating for the item
- `S` is average rating for all items
- `g` is number of votes for the item
- `m` is a minimal number of votes for the item to be included in your ranking.

It works really well for [Filmweb](http://www.filmweb.pl/rankings/film/world).

You'd have to modify it a little bit. Check how it would work if you counted a *view* of an item as *rating* it with `1.0` mark, and an *add to favourites* as `5.0`. Try `m = 1` at first. Possibly you'd like to change `5.0` to something like...

```
rating_for_a_favourite = number_of_all_views / number_of_all_adds
```

... perhaps with some factor < 1.0.

Try it. :-)

**Edit**: Using this formula, you could easily incorporate real rating (e.g. 1-5 stars) of items to your website, *besides* including views and favourites into `rating`.